# Is there a way to limit user/group access per Product in Kiwi TCMS?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

We are exploring a few options, need to understand if there is a feature to limit user per project in Kiwi TCMS?

Looked up in the documentation could not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are groups and permissions but the way the Django framework works doesn't actually allow to have these per object. There is nothing like projects within the base Kiwi TCMS application itself. That is to say if you have permissions to access something that means pretty much access to everything else of the same type within the application.

However there is a multi-tenant add-on, which provides a more powerful isolation layer. The isolation is done on the basis of a name space (e.g. domain name) + database schema. Additionally for each tenant admin must configure which users can access it. If you want true isolation (per team, per project, etc) then you should use the multi-tenant architecture.

This is what Kiwi TCMS itself uses to host our SaaS offering.

Source code and info can be found at https://github.com/kiwitcms/tenants.